# How to Remote Connection to mongodb server

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I added `bindIpAll: true` and I have a db with user and pass, when I run this Command **from Ubuntu Terminal, everything is ok** and I can Connect to db, But When I run That from my Laptop I Get This Error:
**Command:**

```
mongo -u user3 -p SOh3ThghgypJPxmt1oOfL myServerIP/db
```

**Error:**

```
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server myServerIP:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I Added My Laptop Ip to server and Solved.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s myyyyyyLaptopIp -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d myyyyyyLaptopIp -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```